# decodeObjectForKey: always returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I am trying to save my object graph to a file and then reload it at a later time, however decodeObjectForKey: always returns nil for any key I specify.

A binary file is created and does have the occasional human readable text in it, i.e., titleTextColor so I think the archiving process is working.

Have I miss-understood how NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver work?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeFloat:titleFontSize forKey:@"titleFontSize"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[UIColor orangeColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:lineSeparatorColor forKey:@"lineSeparatorColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:bodyTextColor forKey:@"bodyTextColor"];
    [encoder encodeFloat:bodyTextFontSize forKey:@"bodyTextFontSize"];
    [encoder encodeObject:backgroundColor forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:tintColor forKey:@"tintColor"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:bodyTextAlignment forKey:@"bodyTextAlignment"];

    [encoder encodeObject:@"Text" forKey:@"Text"];
}

+ (void) saveToFile {
    // Get the shared instance
    PSYDefaults *sharedInstance = [PSYDefaults sharedInstance];    

    // Serialise the object
    NSData *serializedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sharedInstance];

    // Get the path and filename of the file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathAndFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ksDefaultsFileName];

    // Write the defaults to a file
    if (serializedObject) [serializedObject writeToFile:pathAndFileName atomically:YES];
}

+ (void) loadFromFile {
    // Get the shared instance
    PSYDefaults *sharedInstance = [PSYDefaults sharedInstance];    

    // Get the path and filename of the file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathAndFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ksDefaultsFileName];

    NSData *codedData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathAndFileName] autorelease];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *defaults = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:codedData];

    // Set the properties of the shared instance
    NSString *test = [defaults decodeObjectForKey:@"Text"];
    NSLog (@"%@", test);
    sharedInstance.titleTextColor = [defaults decodeObjectForKey:@"titleTextColor"];

    [defaults release];
}
```

**EDIT: Based on advice from DarkDust:**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.titleFontSize = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"titleFontSize"] floatValue];
        self.titleTextColor = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"titleTextColor"];
        self.lineSeparatorColor = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lineSeparatorColor"];
        self.bodyTextColor = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bodyTextColor"];
        self.bodyTextFontSize = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bodyTextFontSize"] floatValue];
        self.backgroundColor = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"backgroundColor"];
        self.tintColor = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tintColor"];
        self.bodyTextAlignment = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bodyTextAlignment"] intValue];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and creating a new instance just to test:

```
+ (void) loadFromFile {
    // Get the shared instance
    PSYDefaults *sharedInstance = [PSYDefaults sharedInstance];    

    // Get the path and filename of the file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathAndFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ksDefaultsFileName];

    NSData *codedData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathAndFileName] autorelease];
    PSYDefaults *newInstance =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:codedData];

    sharedInstance.titleTextColor = newInstance.titleTextColor;
}
```

**EDIT - Update (needed to encode floats and ints as NSNumbers)**

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:titleFontSize] forKey:@"titleFontSize"];
    [encoder encodeObject:titleTextColor forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:lineSeparatorColor forKey:@"lineSeparatorColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:bodyTextColor forKey:@"bodyTextColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:bodyTextFontSize] forKey:@"bodyTextFontSize"];
    [encoder encodeObject:backgroundColor forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:tintColor forKey:@"tintColor"];
    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bodyTextAlignment] forKey:@"bodyTextAlignment"];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You serialized using a single root object, but you try to deserialize using a key which doesn't exist at that level.

You want `unarchiveObjectWithData:`, as in:

```
NSData *codedData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathAndFileName] autorelease];
PSYDefaults *decodedDefaults = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:codedData];
```

Note that you'll also need to implement `initWithCoder:` as counterpart to `encodeWithCoder:`. Even though it seems you want to have a singleton here, NSCoding demands to create a new object here due to `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sharedInstance]`.

If you want to en/decode the fields without creating a new instance of `PSYDefaults`, then you need to use [-[NSKeyedArchiver initForWritingWithMutableData:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSKeyedArchiver/initForWritingWithMutableData:) and pass that archive to a method  similar to your `encodeWithCoder:` (but you should give it a different name then). Then you'd write a counterpart which reads the fields back via a `NSKeyedUnarchiver` where you do use `decodeObjectForKey:` and friends for each field.

You also might want to read Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Comment: This is great advice, thanks.  I realised my folly with unarchiving and now create a new instance and have implemented an initWithCoder.  I think I am almost there, initWithCoder is called when NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchives my object graph.  However I am getting bad access after calling initWithCoder any ideas?  Dave

Comment: Doh, scrub that.  Releasing the newInstance when it is already autoreleased was the problem.  Thanks for all your help!  Dave

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your object using:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:filePath];
```

and load it using:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
```

I use above methods to save NSDictionary with custom object to a file.

And also you should have the function initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder in your object.
Which decode the data using

```
[decoder decodeObjectFoyKey:yourKey];
```

Comment: Thanks Hanon, DarkDust sorted in the end.  Gave your answer +1 for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem with `NSCoder's` `decodeObjectForKey` method while using `FXForm` - it crashed without any explanation.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.someObject = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someObject"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

The reason was in memory issues. Commonly, looks like when there is no explanation of a bug in logs, it means, it's a memory issue. I forgot to use correct property attribute - copy. I used assign instead. This is correct code:

```
@interface MyClass : : NSObject <FXForm, NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, copy) SomeClass *someObject;

@end
```

Just in case somebody meets this problem too.